# Описать прямоугольник вокруг контура

Tags: алгоритм, графика

Стоит задача найти площадь (длину и ширину) прямоугольника, описывающего контур, состоящий из примитивов (дуги и линии). У меня есть координаты точек, образующих эти примитивы (красные точки на картинке)

[image: рисунок1]

Есть еще координаты центов дуг, но, возможно, они не нужны сейчас. Я решал задачу по следующему алгоритму:

1. составлял отрезки из всех точек, то есть, соединял каждую точку с каждой;
2. искали среди отрезков те, которые перпендикулярны между собой;
3. среди пар перпендикулярных отрезков находил те, у которых наибольшее произведение. Это и были ширина и длина нужного прямоугольника (а, следовательно, и площадь).

Этот алгоритм работал хорошо для большинства фигур, в том числе и для той, что приведена на первом рисунке. Но вот столкнулся с фигурой со второго рисунка:

[image: рисунок2]

Понятно, что тут мой алгоритм не сработал. Ширину он выбирает верную (нижнее основание), а вот длину - нет, т.к. нет координаты центра нижнего основания, что бы можно было построить отрезок, соединяющий центр нижнего основание с самой верхней точкой.

Был вариант найти центр нижнего основания, но этот вариант только для второго рисунка. И если вдруг возникнет ситуация с рисунка 3, то алгоритм снова становится нерабочим. Потому что отрезок, соединяющий верхнюю точку с центром нижнего основания не будет перпендикулярен нижнему основанию.

[image: рисунок3]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вариант общего алгоритма нахождения длины и ширины прямоугольника, описывающего контур.

Comment: Дайте **точное** определение того, что для вас есть «прямоугольник, описывающий контур».

Comment: Если имеется в виду, что прямоугольник нельзя поворачивать (стороны параллельны сторонам изображения), я бы прошелся по всем точкам и нашел минимум & максимум по оси X и Y, но этот вариант не сработает для первого вашего изображения (там кривая сверху будет выходить за прямоугольник). Чтобы эту проблему решить, я бы добавил намного больше точек по контурам и прошелся, грубо говоря, "по каждому контуру с маленьким шагом" (например, в 1 пиксель).
Это в случае, если бы у меня были только "кривая" и "прямая". Но если использовать вместо кривой круг с его радиусом и центром, можно считать быстрее

Comment: @VladD, к сожаланию прям точного определения нет. Но как я представляю, это прямоугольник с наименьшей площадью, в который можно вписать выбранную фигуру.

Comment: @therainycat, из точек есть только то, что выделено. Можно, конечно, программно посчитать точки, но это значительно увеличит время обработки (нахождение нужного прямоугольника) одной фигуры.

Comment: @rudolfninja просто не уточнялось, каким образом ведется просчет - программой или вручную. На самом деле, программа очень быстро просчитает все - например, прямые не нужно разбивать на маленькие отрезки, достаточно точек начала и конца. А кривые, как я понял, это кривые Безье, их тоже можно очень быстро просчитать. Не знаю, какой объем данных надо обработать, но такие фигуры можно десятками, а то и сотнями / тысячами в секунду обрабатывать. Уточните, какие данные есть на входе (формат файла / массив данных), возможно я вам напишу скрипт.

Comment: По сути, вам нужен вариант [вращающегося штангенциркуля](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers). На каждом из отрезков вам придётся оптимизировать произведение. Это должно быть просто для случая угла (минимум произведения синусов, рассчитывается простым дифференцированием) и немного сложнее для случая окружности.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала решить более простую задачу, где круглых сегментов нету.

Comment: "искали среди отрезков те, которые перпендикулярны между собой" - а если таких нет? например, даны вершины треугольника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот наброски по *частичному* решению вашей проблемы, для многоугольников, без сегментов окружностей.

Я попробую провести аналогию с [методом «вращающегося штангенциркуля»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) (не знаю хорошего русского названия).

Рассмотрим охватывающие прямоугольники, у которых основание идёт под некоторым углом φ к горизонтали. Пусть S(φ) — площадь этого прямоугольника. Наша цель — найти экстремум этой функции на [0, π/2).

Пускай для начала φ = 0. Рассмотрим охватывающий прямоугольник:

[image: скан, да]

В нашем случае, стороны охватывающего прямоугольника проходят через вершины *A*₁, *A*₄ и *A*₁, *A*₅ соответственно. Для начала, найдём диапазон значений угла φ, при которых это всё ещё будет так. Найдём сначала, как далеко можно повернуть нижнее основание, чтобы нижняя сторона всё ещё опиралась на вершину *A*₁. Этим углом будет минимальный из углов лучей *A*₁*A*₂, *A*₁*A*₃, *A*₁*A*₄, *A*₁*A*₅. Аналогично находим диапазоны поворота для остальных четырёх сторон. Пересечение этих диапазонов и даст тот диапазон значений φ, внутри которого охватывающий прямоугольник опирается на те же вершины.

Для этого диапазона найдём экстремальное значение площади. Пусть угол отрезка *A*₁*A*₄ с горизонталью равен φ₁, а угол отрезка *A*₁*A*₅ — φ₂. Обозначим *d*₁ = |*A*₁*A*₄|, *d*₂ = |*A*₁*A*₅| Вертикальная сторона прямоугольника равна *d*₁ sin(φ − φ₁), горизонтальная — *d*₂ sin(φ + π/2 − φ₂) = *d*₂ cos(φ − φ₂).

Площадь равна *d*₁*d*₂ sin(φ − φ₁) cos(φ − φ₂) = *d*₁*d*₂ (sin (2φ − φ₁ − φ₂) + sin (φ₂ − φ₁))/2. Для того, чтобы найти экстремум этой величины, можно отбросить константы *d*₁*d*₂/2 и sin (φ₂ − φ₁), и вспомнить, что минимум у синуса достигается в точке, где аргумент равен 3π/2 + *k* · 2π, или на концах отрезка.

Сравнив между собой значение площади на концах отрезка, а также в точках вида 3π/4 + (φ₁ + φ₂)/2 + *k* · π (если они попадают на отрезок), получим минимум на этом отрезке.

Окей. Дальше просто. Поворачивая основание дальше, переходим к рассмотрению случая, когда опорной точкой нижнего основания является *A*₅, повторяем рассмотрение на этом отрезке значений φ. Продолжаем до тех пор, пока φ не достигнет величины π/2.

Всё.

---

Вам понадобится ещё обобщить этот алгоритм для случая кривых сторон. Здесь опорная точка будет катиться по дуге с изменением φ, что, в принципе, позволяет провести такое же рассмотрение.

Дерзайте!

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел русский вариант предложенного алгоритма (Диаметр множества точек). Буду пробовать реализовать его. Вроде как, с его помощью можно решить мою задачу.